# How did the Denpa Kyoushi manga end?

Tags: denpa-kyoushi

I have read the raws, but since my japanese isn't very good, I'm not entirely sure about what happened. According to what I understood, Junichirou built a time machine and went to the future. More precisely, the manga shows that he's currently at Africa. But I still have many questions:

- Why exactly did he go to future? Was he "sacrificing himself?"
- Won't he come back to the present? What about his sister and friends?

I'm quite confused, as you can see. Thank you very much for your attention!